# Setting default homepage for website domain

Tags: html

I am wondering how do you set up the Homepage for a website.

When you visit `www.example.com/home.html`
That would be the home page.

But when you visit `www.example.com/`
I would like it to go to /home.html

Currently it goes to Index of `/` (File listing Format)
I'm using Digiweb, an Irish Hosting Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any administration panel for your host (cpanel, plesk, etc)? Usually you can edit this settings there.

If not, look for the file **.htaccess** (i guess you're using Apache as your server, if not tell me). If doesn't exists create a new file with the name .htaccess (use the point before the h!).

Open that file, and look for the **DirectoryIndex**. If already exists add home.html as the first word after it, if not create and just paste this.

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

Comment: I don't know if it's Apache, but I have located a "Directory Indexes", but when I paste your code (edit with the name) it doesn't work.

Comment: Where have you located that, on your panel administration or you're talking about the .htaccess file?

Comment: I located it on the Web Options.

Comment: I found the htaccess, it says create file.

Comment: What do I do now? It has /.htmaster/.ok_user

Comment: The "create file" is a button right? Click it and create the .htaccess file. Then add  DirectoryIndex to it. If it's easier, open the file manager of your host and go to the public root folder where you've the home.html. There you can manually create the .htaccess

Comment: I started using an FTP client, easier way to find the file... I have 
**AuthType basic
AuthName "Secured area"
AuthUserFile /hsphere/local/home/username/.htmaster/.ok_user
Require valid-user**

Comment: Sorry but i haven't understood very well your reply. Did you found the .htaccess and added the DirectoryIndex? It's already solved? If the question is solved, please mark the answer as done. If not, tell me what you're missing (if you found the .htaccess file and don't know what to do, just add that line at the top)

Comment: I appreciate the help, when I do one thing another thing breaks, I've added that line into the file (with the actual filename) but before that my website won't display ... url  www.pauliedunne.com and mainpage is www.pauliedunne.com/index.html

Comment: I asked another question about the problem but people closed it.

Comment: Right now you're asking for authentication (that's why it opens a dialog asking username and password). Can you paste your .htacces? Paste it on your question (edit the question) so i can see what's wrong, but don't paste it on another comment!

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I'm very frustrated, if you have Skype, could you temp add pauliedunne.

Answer (score -1):

create a new file name **index.php**
and write this php code

```
<? header('location:home.html'); ?>
```

Comment: That sends the website on a loop, but does not actually do what I want.

Comment: can you explain more you want to create a redirection for home.html and do not show index of/ page ?

Comment: I have my website, in my domain folder, so www.example.com/index.html is the path to what I want, but when people type in the URL bar www.example.com ... I want it to go to www.example.com/index.html

Comment: some hosts does not set html index first do use a php index add a new file : index.php and put this code on it **<? header('location:index.html'); ?>** or try with this **<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=index.html" />** be sure that the index have .html extention not .htm  use this and replay

Comment: Read what i've posted on Dusty answer. Redirect shoudln't be a solution at all. Either set the content to a new file index.html or set the default loaded document as home.html on htaccess. Don't create index.html just to redirect

Answer (score -1):

Redirect them by placing:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/home.html" />
```

in the `<head>` section of your `index.html` page. In this example, the `0` is the time before the page is redirected. The http://www.example.com/home.html line is the specific webpage that the page is to be redirected to.

Comment: if home.html is the main page you shouldn't redirect from index.html, that's an extra request for the server that can be avoided

Comment: I would change the homepage location from `http://www.example.com/home.html` to  `http://www.example.com/index.html` and that would solve your problem by avoiding the need to redirect.

Comment: Is there a reason for having your homepage saved as home.html?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. If it still doesn't work, it may be a deprecated solution.

Comment: if you save your homepage html file as `index.html` and you put it in your root directory \ then you should be able to see it when you load your website. Hold ctrl and refresh your homepage. If you still have problems, I would call your hosting provider.

Comment: I have
logs
mydomainname
stats

Do I put it right beside those, or in mydomainname folder?

Comment: I would think in the folder that contains your stats and logs. It should just be a forward slash `/`. Also you could put the file in both folders. The one in your `mydomainname` folder could have the contents of the file say `I'm in the mydomainname folder` just to be certain